# Eclipse crash on startup: startJavaVM

Tags: java-7, eclipse-kepler, jvm-crash

I have an Eclipse Kepler installed and I use it for monthes, with a JDK 7u65 installed. I recently tried to install a JDK 7u67 which failed (don't know why). It is the same when trying to install a JRE 7u67. I then removed the folder of the JDK 7u67.

At startup, Eclipse is telling me the following:
[image]

To resolve this, I tried to tweak my eclipse.ini (just added -vm arg and its value):

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

As a result, Eclipse just crashes. Here is an extract of the crashlog.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff96474017 CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 39
1   eclipse_1508.so                 0x00000001000e283a findSymbol + 66
2   eclipse_1508.so                 0x00000001000e09b0 startJavaJNI + 206
3   eclipse_1508.so                 0x00000001000dfd6f startJavaVM + 9
4   eclipse_1508.so                 0x00000001000de2f9 _run + 4611
5   eclipse_1508.so                 0x00000001000dece2 run + 434
6   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x00000001000018e3 original_main + 1809
7   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001eb5 main + 1230
8   org.eclipse.platform.ide        0x0000000100001090 start + 52
```

Just to be sure, I tried installing another Eclipse (Luna), but the result is the same. Any idea?

EDIT : Here are some environment variables defined on my machine :

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/remidoolaeghe/Developper/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/Library/glassfish3/glassfish/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Possibly something to do with Eclipse bug [390071](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390071)

Comment: I've just taken a look, but this does not seem to be the same issue. In this bug ticket, there is a story of eclipse updating and extracting with The UnArchiver. My eclipse is installed on my machine for monthes and worked for a long time.